# Raylib c++ what is the type of colors?

Tags: c++, raylib

So I am new to c++ and raylib and want to save a raylib color as a class attribute but I don't know how to. I tried using the auto keyword like this `auto cellColor = WHITE;` but then I get the following error `error: non-static data member declared with placeholder 'auto'` so I think that I need to specify the type and not use auto but when I have no idea what type to use or how to find out. Does anyone know the type I need to use or any workaround for this?

Comment: Use your IDE. Position the cursor on WHITE. Press whatever button takes you to the definition. Look at the definition of WHITE. What type is it? Use that type.

Comment: Thanks the type is `struct Color`. Can you post the comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://robloach.github.io/raylib-cpp/classraylib_1_1_color.html) Look at the Color(unsigned char red,...) constructor

```
// custom color with r,g,b values of your choosing 

auto color = raylib::Color(1,2,3);
// or use the statics (pre-defined colors)
auto color = raylib::Color::Magenta();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could directly do:

```
Color{/*R*/, /*G*/, /*B*/, /*A*/}
```

and it will return a color value